# How to use EF6 with ASP.NET Core 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I created an ASP.NET Core 1 project and using .Net Core 1.0 framework. And want to use the **Entity Framework 6**.
I follow this tutorials https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html and when I try to migrate with the statement:

```
PM> Add-Migration MyFirstMigration
```

then it shows me:

```
The EntityFramework package is not installed on project 'IndustryCloud'.
```

It is possible to use EF6 with ASP.NET Core 1?

Comment: Are you running on .NET Core, or the full .NET Framework?

Comment: You can use either .Net Core 1.0 Framework together with Entity Framework Core 1.0, or .NET Framework 4.5+ with Entity Framework 6. _In both options_, you can use ASP.NET Core 1.0.

Comment: I am running on .NET Core 1.0.

Comment: You see, the different answers come from a fact that an answer to a question _is it possible to use EF6 with ASP.NET Core 1?_ is *yes*, but an answer to a question _is it possible to use EF6 with ASP.NET Core 1 running on .NET Core 1.0?_ is *no*

Comment: So there is no entity framework for ASP.NET Core 1 yet? So, how can I use EF only with .NET Core 1 for console application?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Entity Framework 6` with ASP.Net Core 1.0. An example application [can be found on Github](https://github.com/mrahhal/Migrator.EF6).

In order to make it work, you have to follow the instructions from the repo (below I paste the crucial parts, but I encourage you to check the ones from repository):

Inside project.json:

> - Remove netcoreapp1.0 from the target frameworks and add net451.
> - Remove everything EF Core and add Migrator.EF6.Tools + EF6 to your dependencies

Inside Startup.cs:

> - Remove everything EF Core related.
> - Simply add your db context to services: `services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>();`

Next:

> Remove the "Migrations" or the "Data/Migrations" folder that EF Core generated.

And finally:

```
dotnet ef migrations enable
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
dotnet ef database update
```

Note that you can use another project called [MR.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework6](https://github.com/mrahhal/MR.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework6) to bridge  Asp.Net Core Identity with Entity Framework 6.

Comment: Then you're not running on .NET Core. Your opening sentence is incorrect.

Comment: @mason sorry, my mistake, I was thinking about ASP.NET Core. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use `Entity Framework 6` with .Net Core 1.0. There is a `Entity Framework Core 1.0` package developed specifically for  `.Net Core 1.0`. You need to install it to use in .Net Core 1.0 project.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/06/27/entity-framework-core-1-0-0-available/

Install using Nuget Package Mangager Console.

`PM>  Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

Add a new migration (If it’s the first one, it will add the neccessary folder structure and classes)

`dotnet ef migrations add {MigrationName}`

Remove the most recent migration.

`dotnet ef migrations remove`

Update the database the latest version (apply all migrations)

`dotnet ef database update`

http://benjii.me/2016/05/dotnet-ef-migrations-for-asp-net-core/

You can find so many articles in google.

Comment: The question did not specifically say whether .NET Core was being used or not. ASP.NET Core can run on the full .NET Framework, not just .NET Core.

Comment: I agree. if you see in the link which he provided. It mentioned .NET core 1.0 as prerequisite. I am sure he is using asp.net core 1.0  on .Net core 1.0.

Comment: How to migrate it?

Comment: I tried it and got `dotnet.exe : No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"At line:1 char:1`. I did install `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`.

Comment: did you update ur `project.json` as mentioned in the article.