# ASP.NET Core 1.0.1 Application Targeting .NET 4.6.x

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, .net-core

Today I decided to create a new ASP.NET Core 1.0.1 application using the Visual Studio 2017 RC Empty template. The application runs and all goes well. Note though that this is the first time I use the all new .NET Core.

Then I decided I want to use EntityFramework 6.x and not EF Core because I am bound to using Oracle instead of SQL Server. Unfortunately, I have spent hours looking at the documentation, blog posts and StackOverflow questions but I still couldn't get it to work.

From what I've read, ASP.NET Core started out with a `project.json` file which then got deprecated (correct me if I'm wrong...) and all the documentation and content online seem to propose solutions using this file.

Accordingly:

1. Is targeting multiple versions of the .NET framework (Core and
   4.6.x) still possible now that the project.json is gone? If so, how?
2. Can I still use the project.json anyway?!

**UPDATE:**

Some of the issues I'm facing are the following:

- I created a class library called "Shared". The type of the project was .NET Standard. I referenced it in the ASP.NET Core application and it worked fine. Then I referenced it from a web application which targets .NET 4.5.2 and I got this error: `Project Shared is not compatible with net452 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2) / win7-x86. Project Shared supports: netstandard1.4 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.4)`
- I tried to install the EntityFramework 6.x Nuget package into the ASP.NET Core application, but I got this error: `One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.`

I guess if someone would point me in the right direction on where to read reliable/up-to-date documentation that would be great. I need to understand what and why this is happening so I can take it from there.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @Mike_G: the error I'm getting is this "One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0."

Comment: Off topic : since you try a new project on new versions, why don't you try version 1.1.0? In topic : you should post your project.json file, it may help !

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38267723/861716

Comment: @kall2sollies: I actually tried that. I used Nuget to update the packages to the latest version right after creating the empty project. Once I did that, the application stopped running: as if a console application has run and then closed. I thought that might be a bug in the tooling since it's not an RTM version of Visual Studio 2017 yet.

Comment: @GertArnold: No, this is not a duplicate. The selected answer recommends a guide that is based on project.json, which is basically what's causing me the confusion in the first place.

Comment: There's more than the selected answer.

Comment: maybe this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37590604/can-not-find-runtime-target-for-framework-netcoreapp-v1-compatible-with-one-of/39534983#39534983

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is targeting multiple versions of the .NET framework (Core and 4.6.x)
>   still possible now that the project.json is gone? If so, how?

You can specify multiple version in **csproj** like below-

Example1:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp1.0;net452</TargetFrameworks>
```

Example2:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp1.1;net462</TargetFrameworks>
```

Refer [Cross-targeting](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/10/19/net-core-tooling-in-visual-studio-15/) section.

> Can I still use the project.json anyway?

You can easily migrate using `dotnet migrate` command. This command generates the exact same csproj file from existing project.json.

Refer [Project Migration](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/10/19/net-core-tooling-in-visual-studio-15/) section.